# Why use detached git worktree?

Tags: git, workflow

What are the advantages and/or appropriate use-cases for setting up a detached worktree in git?  I'm particularly interested in situations that involve workflows that involve a chain of servers (eg, localhost -> staging server -> live server).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but whats a detached worktree? I only know "detached HEAD"

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by “detached worktree”?

Comment: @doub1ejack seems to be referring to the situation where the git repo is on one place and the worktree in another, rather than the repo being the .git directory in the worktree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big advantage (that I see, at least) is the ability to [publish changes to a live server](http://blog.ekynoxe.com/2011/10/22/git-post-receive-for-multiple-remote-branches-and-work-trees/) without forcing the git repository itself to be located in the live area. You can throw the repo wherever you want, and use a detached worktree to checkout.

Comment: TIL about the worktree setting. That was new to me (didn’t expect that :P). Thanks, +1!

Comment: @poke Hey no problem! It's honestly one of my favorite Git features. Freaking love it. You can set up `post-receive` hooks to checkout different branches to different locations, so literally all you have to do to test or go live is put your stuff in the right branch and push it. Coolest thing ever.

Comment: Are there any security benefits to keeping the repository out of the web directory?

Comment: Sure. If you're running something dynamic on the server, leaving the repo in the web directory gives everybody access to your backend. If it's a backend you've already open-sourced, you may not care.

Comment: There is also some value to keeping the repo away from development activity. Another repo of mine was unexpectedly affected by Drupal's commandline tool Drush during a core update.  (Affected ~= deleted)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `git`s development logs would be the best place to look for a definitive use case. But, practically speaking, I know that sub-modules use them now (the associated repository structures are stored under `.git/modules` now, while the working tree is in the expected place relative to your own working tree. I've also used it to check out a different revision for inspection purposes without having to `stash` or `commit` first - the second checkout can then be trashed when your done with it. I don't think you would want two active working directories on different commits, with the intent of committing additional changes, though. That path smells of havoc. I suppose I could imagine some random corporate edict that all repositories must be on a particular file system that's backed up, but you can put your work directory somewhere else; although that's obviously an extreme case of someone "not getting it"...